# How to apply sqrt to vector in Cython?

Tags: cython

Hello I'm really beginner to Cython or C-based language.
I have a problem to get a square of a vector.

I have a vector(each value is double type):

```
x = [1, 4, 9]
```

and I want to get:

```
y = [1, 2, 3]
```

How can I get this vector?
A solution I thought is:

```
cdef floating[::1] y = x
for i in range(length):
    y[i] = x[i] ** 0.5
```

But in this way it's too slow. I want to **acclerate** this.
Can I use sqrt or square function from libc.math in this case?

---

Edit:

If I want to get a vector like 1/3 root (like [1, 8, 27] -> [1,2,3]) what function should I use instead of sqrt?

Comment: Note that `x[i]**0.5` has python interaction, so it's slow inside a loop. Instead, use the C function `sqrt` from libc.math, as you already mentioned. It's also highly recommended to type the index variable, i.e. `cdef int i`.

Comment: @joni I believe `x[i]**0.5` should end up calling libc `pow` so should avoid Python interactions (assuming `x` and `i` are correctly typed so that the indexing works quickly). libc `sqrt` would probably be slightly better though. It should probably be `y[i] = y[i]**0.5` though (notice `y[i]` on the right-hand side)

Answer (score 0):

### Quick win

First you should check if your function is already implemented in Numpy. If so, it will probably be a very fast (C/C++) implementation.

This is the case for your function:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1, 4, 9])
y = np.sqrt(x)
#> array([ 1, 2, 3])
```

### With Numpy arrays

Alternatively (following @joni's comment), you can use np arrays just for the input/output and compute the function element-wise using C/C++:

```py
cimport numpy as cnp
import numpy as np
from libc.math cimport sqrt

cpdef cnp.ndarray[double, ndim=1] cy_sqrt_np(cnp.ndarray[double, ndim=1] x):
   cdef Py_ssize_t i, l=x.shape[0]
   cdef np.ndarray[double, 1] y = np.empty(l)
   for i in range(l):
      y[i] = sqrt(x[i])
   return y
```

### With C++ vectors

Lastly, here is a possible implementation with C++ vectors and automatic conversion from/to python lists:

```py
from libc.math cimport sqrt
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cpdef vector[double] cy_sqrt_vec(vector[double] x):
    cdef Py_ssize_t i, l = x.size()
    cdef vector[double] y
    y.reserve(l)
    for i in range(l):
        y.push_back(sqrt(x[i]))
    return y
```

Some things to keep in mind in this case and the previous:

- We initialize the `y` vector to be empty, and then allocate space for it with `reserve()`. According to [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25108854/initializing-the-size-of-a-c-vector) this seems to be a good option.
- We use a typed `i` in the for loop, and use `push_back` to assign new values.
- We use `sqrt` from `libc.math` to avoid using Python code inside the loop.
- We type the input of the function to be `vector[double]`. This automatically adds convenient type conversions from other python types (e.g., list of ints).

## Time comparison

We define a random input `x` to avoid cached results polluting our measures:

```py
%%timeit  -n 10000 -r 7 x = gen_x()
y = np.sqrt(x)
#> executed in 177ms, finished 16:16:57 2022-04-19
#> 2.3 µs ± 241 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit -n 10000 -r 7 x = gen_x()
y = x**.5
#> executed in 194ms, finished 16:16:51 2022-04-19
#> 2.46 µs ± 256 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit  -n 10000 -r 7 x = gen_x()
y = cy_sqrt(x)
executed in 359ms, finished 16:17:02 2022-04-19
4.9 µs ± 274 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit  -n 10000 -r 7 x = list(gen_x())
y = cy_sqrt_vec(x)
executed in 2.85s, finished 16:17:11 2022-04-19
40.4 µs ± 1.31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

As expected, the `np.sqrt` version wins. Besides, the vector allocation looks comparatively slower.

Comment: If you preallocate the vector's space, it's safe to use direct assignment `y[i] = sqrt(x[i])`. This should be faster than .push_back().

Comment: @joni do you know how to do that in Cython? I checked several StackOverflow questions & [vector.pxd](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/libcpp/vector.pxd) but didn't find any satisfying answer.

Comment: Still, thanks to the `reserve` operation, the `push_back` doesn't need to reallocate memory.

Comment: Yeah, but `push_back()` checks whether it needs to reallocate memory whenever it's called, so it's definitely slower than a direct assignment. It's just `y[i] = sqrt(x[i])` since Cython wraps the vectors `operator[]`-method. That being said, I don't think it's needed to use a C++ vector here. A simple memoryview of a numpy ndarray should be enough. In addition, returning a np.ndarray instead of a python list is more convenient, IMO.

Comment: The function isn't acclerated. Is there no function to calculate line by line? (not value by value)

Comment: The trouble with the vector version is that you have a type conversion to/from a Numpy list for both the argument and the return value.

Comment: @DavidW I know (and that's why it is so slow), yet it is the only way I can think of using only Python lists (I guess you meant *Python* and not *Numpy* lists), in case the user wanted to use only the Python standard library,.